# Converting data from CSV string to float

Tags: c++

How do I convert a string from my CSV file (excel worksheet) to a float value? Suppose that my CSV sheet contains:

```
0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1
```

and my code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("data1.csv");
    string line;
    getline(myfile,line,',');
    cout << line;
}
```

I am able to obtain `line` as a string, specifically type `Ss` but I need to convert the `line` into a `float`. How do I do that?

Comment: consider using a ibrary like [libcsv](https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv) for parsing csv files.

Comment: First Google hit gives header-only library https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser. Or check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it plain C++ without additional libraries: Don't read strings, read floats:

```
float value;
char delim;
if( !( is >> value >> delim ) && ( delim == ',' || delim == '\n' ) )
    // format error
```

Comment: 13 9 C:\Users\Migs\Desktop\Test-Codes\testing2.cpp [Error] 'is' was not declared in this scope

This was my error trying the code!

Comment: That was a sample in which from context should be clear that `is` is a `std::ifstream`. Call it what you want.